# SQL exist clause is always true

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning SQL using PostgreSQL as DBMS and I'm having some problem with a query that seems easy.
I'm supposed to find apps that have their language or their year different from all the others app.
The App table has 3 attributes: id(unique for each app),year,language

That's my solution which is not working (no result):

```
select p.id, p.language, p.year
from app p 
where not exists (select *
             from app p2
             where (p.id!=p2.id) AND (p.language=p2.language OR p.year=p2.year))
```

There are the entries in my table:

[image: These]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That isn't exactly the right logic.  That would check that that language/year pair is not repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this as two separate comparisons:

```
select p.id, p.language, p.year
from app p 
where not exists (select 1
                  from app p2
                  where p.id <> p2.id AND p.year = p2.year
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from app p2
                  where p.id <> p2.id AND p.language = p2.language
                 ) ;
```

The problem with combining them into one statement is that either comparison overrides the other.  So, if another row exists with a duplicate `language`, then you have a matching row and the `not exists` filter takes effect.  There is no need to even look at `year`.